# How to run Docker Deployments at IBM Bluemix Expertises

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, dockerfile

1. A Recommend way for Deploying Docker Images is via 
   (a) bx cs 
   (b) cf ic 
   and why so ?
2. How to run a Docker Image from Private Registry (registry.ng.bluemix.net/namespace/image) ?
3. How to deploy and run various Docker Images (nodejs + mongoose) in terms of micro-services ?
4. Are you sure, that we can deploy and run Docker image using kubernetes via bx cs (or) is that only we can deploy and run docker image using cf ic ?
5. Any short example apps or steps for deploying and running docker image in kubernetes with nodejs connecting mongodb ?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at the information at the following URL about acceptable posts. This post is likely to be closed because it does not follow the Stack Overflow guidelines.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Docker images on IBM Bluemix Container Service. Generally, you use the `bx cs` prefix for commands relating to managing your Kubernetes clusters.

Here is a link to the documentation that explains how to use images from your private IBM Bluemix Container Registry or Dockerhub: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_cluster.html#cs_apps_images

Hope that helps!